# Pass something to render function

Tags: reactjs, react-router

### Current routes:

```js
// React render() return example
<Switch>
  <Route path="/" exact render={this.renderPage}/>
  <Route path="/search" render={this.renderPage}/>
  <Route path="/profile" render={this.renderPage}/>
  <Route render={this.renderPage}/>
</Switch>

// here's the simplified method that Route-s call if path matches
renderPage(props) {
  // JS logic is here

  return [
    <ItemHeader key="header"/>,
    <ItemWrapper key="wrapper">
      {/* this is what the question is about: */}
      {/* how do I pass this dynamic Component here or even hint about it? */}
      <Component someProp={varBasedOnJSLogicAbove}/>
    </Wrapper>
  ];
}
```

How to pass any data to `renderPage` method?

I need to pass my component as variable (or any hint really - string *etc*) to `renderPage` method because I need to tell it what component I want it to render.

#### Why do you even need `renderPage` method?

There's JavaScript logic and I also need to wrap my `Component` with other components.

---

#### 1. Why don't you use `component` prop on `Route`?

```js
<Route path="/profile" component={Profile}/>
```

Because I need to wrap the component and inject some data into it, like in `renderPage` method.

---

#### 2. Why don't you create a separate React component and do all the `renderPage` logic and wraping in it? You could pass everything you need as `props`, etc:

```js
<CustomRoute path="/profile" component={Profile} anyThing="ILikeToPass"/>
```

Tried it, unfortunately it breaks `Switch` (I really need it), `Route` has to be direct child.

---

#### 3. Why don't you use different method for every route? E.g `renderProfile`.

20 methods and each has exactly the same code except different `Component`? No thanks!

---

#### 4. Why don't you just pass the data as function/method arguments?

```js
<Route path="/profile" render={this.renderPage(Component, 'foo')}/>
// or
<Route path="/profile" render={() => this.renderPage(Component, 'bar')}/>
```

Doesn't work as needed. First option seems to overwrite the `props` (I need those) that React Router passes to my method and if you use arrow function - it passes only `props`, not my args.

#### 5. Why don't you use `pathname` and figure it out yourself?

Use a single `Route` without `path` prop and do all the pathname parsing and logic in my method? That's a big if not *the* point of using a router and `Route`-s.. I don't want to rebuild the router.

Comment: Did not use react-router render function before, but if it passes props as a argument, why not try: <Route path="/profile" render={(props) => this.renderPage(props, Component, 'bar')}/>

Comment: @KamilSocha Im shocked that it never occurred to me. If you want reputation, answer this question. I hate to use inline arrow functions inside React render but it seems that I have no other choice in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is an answer:

Why not try:

```
<Route path="/profile" render={(props) => this.renderPage(props, Component, 'bar')}/>
```